# how to activate two links at the same time with one click on a link

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I need some help here. I know there are some real smart people here.
how can i make two different links fire at the same time when somebody clicks on my link.
1. is the auto download and when that is happening at the same time they go to link 2 an explanation page or such.
i have no HTML code, nor do i know how to set it up..but I'm happy to re-compensate with a small donation.

I placed a drawing to exemplify:
[image]

Hopefully that will clear things a bit better.!

Comment: Is the user not going to have to agree to download the "whatever" it is you are offering to them?

Comment: it states on the banner, when they click they know what they are downloading..

Comment: @user3100826 what is your website made with? Did you use a CMS, or was one of those "pre-build" templates, or something else? I see you tagged Android, how is it related? Also... "donation"? Are you trying to hire via StackOverflow? then that would be via [Careers.StackOverflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) otherwise contact the users directly (if they has posted contact info in their profile) or go for a freelancing service.

Comment: @user3100826 Yes, but I think people would expect that they click or tap the banner ad, link etc, and then perhaps they are redirected to another page that explains, and also then starts the download, usually with a confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a Javascript listener to the download link. Something along the lines of ...

```
$('#my-download-link').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href='myotherpage.html';
  }, 1000);
});
```

The `setTimeout` is useful here to ensure the download has been triggered before redirecting.

Comment: could you show me how? im realy not a pro in these things and dont forget the link is a banner on a external site.

Comment: Do you have some HTML code you could show us, so I can adapt my solution to your particular case? Just edit your first post and add it

Comment: im realy sory Samuel,, i dont have no html, i was thinking like a redirect, but now it comes to html programming, is tehre no html script i can upload to my host(website) that does this

Comment: I'm afraid what you want to do is not achievable without some minimal coding... If you use a Content Managemnent System like Wordpress or Joomla you could search their plugins directory, they might have something to do this, but otherwise, you will need to dig into the code at least a little.

Comment: do you know how to do this "little coding" lol, how can i contact you??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are working jQuery and you are at a novice level. First, you begin with a document ready function, as always. Inside that you put your click listener, in this case "#navigation a" is the selector. Now whatever actions you need can go sequentially inside of this function. For example, below I am removing a class and then adding another one. But you can fire multiple clicks, cascade functions, whatever you want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#navigation a").click(function(event){
                $("#navigation a").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                                    // you could put function calls here
            });
```

Notice how when you refer to your selector object a second time or more, you can use (this) as a ref. However, if your code gets more complex than this, you will want to learn a framework so that multiple things can be updated at once automatically, rather than manually firing individual function calls. Hope this helps.